# Is there another word for a sub-team specialized in a certain subject matter please?

Tags: synonyms

Is there another word I can use to name a sub-team specialized in a certain subject matter? A few of us within a leadership group are getting together across job functions to form a sub-team for Food Safety. Purpose of group is to update each other across related functions, agree then communicate to the clients to whom we consult. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will this be a permanent team, or will it be disbanded after its job is done?

Comment: hi, it will be permanent because the job is on-going

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Although there's nothing wrong with either *unit* or *committee* per se, if *sub-team* has already been ruled out, than so must the larger *team* be ruled out—and *team* is synonymous with both *unit* and *committee*.

I had been going to suggest [*task force*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/task%20force), which is a group formed for a specific purpose, but a comment under the question clarified that the *sub-team* would be permanent—and task forces are normally disbanded when their jobs are done. (Although not commonly done, so it would be a little unusual, the term could be used on a more permanent basis if it was desired.)

However, drawing from terminology used in technical and professional fields, I suggest the following:

**subject-matter expert (SME)**

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject-matter_expert):

> A **subject-matter expert (SME)** is a person who is an authority in a particular area or topic …
>
> In engineering and technical fields, an SME is the one who is an authority in the design concept, calculations and performance of a system or process.
>
> In the scientific and academic fields subject matter experts are recruited to perform peer reviews, and are used as oversight personnel to review reports in the accounting and financial fields.
>
> A lawyer in an administrative agency may be designated an SME if he or she specializes in a particular field of law, such as tort, intellectual property rights, etc. A law firm may seek out and use an SME as an expert witness.

Of note is that the person who wrote this article is pronouncing *SME* as if it were an initialism: "*an* ***s-m-e.***" However, in my professional line of work in the technology industry, everybody I know has always pronounced it as an acronym: "*a* ***smee***."

While *SME* can refer to an individual who is an expert in a field, it can also refer to a group of such people. So when, for example, somebody means to say, "Ask the group of experts on the design team," they can either say *ask the design SMEs [people]* or *ask the design SME [group of experts]*.

At least in my experience, *SME* is often kept singular, whether we refer to an individual or a team. We can also say that somebody is *part of a SME*. It's a blurring of the definition that's understood from context.

---

So, in the case of this question, you could say the same thing in a few ways, where its reference to a person or group is implied.

As a group:

> Let's create a Food Safety *SME*.

As inviduals:

> Let's create a team of Food Safety *SMEs*.

Ambiguously (where it could refer to either a group or an individual):

> Let's use a Food Safety *SME*.

Comment: I'd regard "subject matter expert" as management jargon, not English as we know it. The word "expert" or "specialist" means exactly the same. Typically, if there is a permanent team dedicated to a particular expert task, you'd just call it a team or a group, maybe even an "office" - everyone expects the "food safety team" or the "food safety office" to possess food safety expertise.

Comment: Yes but the OP clearly isn't a native English speaker - he can probably be forgiven for asking questions in mangled jargon, it doesn't mean it's ideal to answer back with it.

Comment: @Steve All you can go on is what's in the question. Everything being equal, I think it's a more reasonable assumption. Otherwise, there would be even fewer answers here than already given. ;) I also don't find there to be any mangled jargon, and the phrasing of the question is fairly well formed; it's better, in fact, than several native speakers I've had as managers in the past.

Comment: Thank you @JasonBassford for your answer which is accompanied by a detailed explanation as to why you offered up SME.

Comment: @Steve Thanks for your perspective!

Answer (score 1):

The term ***[unit](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unit)***  may fit your context:

> a group of people living or working together, especially for a particular purpose.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

> Food Safety Unit

Comment: Not sure why this would be down-voted. Seems a more than reasonable suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

***Committee***
From Merriam-Webster’s unabridged:

1. a body of persons delegated to consider, investigate, or take action upon and usually to report concerning some matter or business;